# What type of beetle is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this beetle in my yard. Wondering what type it is. 
[image][image]

Comment: Please add the location. By the way, are you in California?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably [*Prionus californicus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prionus_californicus), which is a coleopteran native to the American west.

Look at the serrate antennae:

[image]

Also, the abdomen looks like the one in your specimen:

[image]